# Clair v4 container setup Updaters URL can't be resolved

Tags: docker, docker-compose, clair

I am trying to set up clair v4 in a container environment but I get some errors resolving some of the updaters URL's Maybe someone can help me out.

I also tried some older Imges Versions and get the same error messages.

The main error is, that I can't resolve the Updater Information from corresponding URLS and I don't know why.

```json
clair-indexer   | {"level":"error","component":"rhel/internal/common/Updater.Get","error":"Get \"https://access.redhat.com/security/data/metrics/container-name-repos-map.json\": context deadline exceeded","time":"2023-12-17T12:02:53Z","message":"error updating mapping file"}
clair-indexer   | {"level":"error","version":"1.1","component":"rhel/internal/common/Updater.Get","error":"Get \"https://access.redhat.com/security/data/metrics/repository-to-cpe.json\": context deadline exceeded","time":"2023-12-17T12:03:03Z","message":"error updating mapping file"}
clair-matcher   | {"level":"error","component":"libvuln/updates/Manager.Run","error":"alpine: error requesting \"https://secdb.alpinelinux.org/last-update\": Get \"https://secdb.alpinelinux.org/last-update\": dial tcp 172.105.78.12:443: i/o timeout","time":"2023-12-17T12:03:13Z","message":"failed constructing factory, excluding from run"}
clair-matcher   | {"level":"error","component":"libvuln/updates/Manager.Run","error":"debian: examining remote: debian: unable to do request: Get \"https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/\": dial tcp 146.75.118.132:443: i/o timeout","time":"2023-12-17T12:03:43Z","message":"failed constructing factory, excluding from run"}
clair-matcher   | {"level":"error","component":"libvuln/updates/Manager.Run","error":"Get \"https://access.redhat.com/security/data/oval/v2/PULP_MANIFEST\": dial tcp 23.213.161.217:443: i/o timeout","time":"2023-12-17T12:04:13Z","message":"failed constructing factory, excluding from run"}
clair-matcher   | {"level":"error","component":"libvuln/updates/Manager.Run","error":"ubuntu: error requesting series collection: Get \"https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/ubuntu/series\": dial tcp 185.125.189.224:443: i/o timeout","time":"2023-12-17T12:04:43Z","message":"failed constructing factory, excluding from run"}
clair-matcher   | {"level":"error","component":"libvuln/updates/Manager.Start","error":"updating errors:\naws-AL2-updater: failed to create client: failed to make request for mirrors: Get \"https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list\": context deadline exceeded\naws-AL1-updater: failed to create client: failed to make request for mirrors: Get \"http://repo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2018.03/updates/x86_64/mirror.list\": context deadline exceeded\nsuse-updater-suse.linux.enterprise.server.12: Get \"https://support.novell.com/security/oval/suse.linux.enterprise.server.12.xml\": dial tcp 130.57.66.5:443: i/o timeout\nphoton-updater-photon2: Get \"https://packages.vmware.com/photon/photon_oval_definitions/com.vmware.phsa-photon2.xml\": dial tcp 2.18.160.25:443: i/o timeout\naws-AL2023-updater: failed to create client: failed to make request for mirrors: Get \"https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/al2023/core/mirrors/latest/x86_64/mirror.list\": context deadline exceeded\nphoton-updater-photon1: Get \"https://packages.vmware.com/photon/photon_oval_definitions/com.vmware.phsa-photon1.xml\": dial tcp 2.18.160.25:443: i/o timeout\nsuse-updater-suse.linux.enterprise.server.15: Get \"https://support.novell.com/security/oval/suse.linux.enterprise.server.15.xml\": dial tcp 130.57.66.5:443: i/o timeout\nsuse-updater-opensuse.leap.15.1: Get \"https://support.novell.com/security/oval/opensuse.leap.15.1.xml\": dial tcp 130.57.66.5:443: i/o timeout\nphoton-updater-photon3: Get \"https://packages.vmware.com/photon/photon_oval_definitions/com.vmware.phsa-photon3.xml\": dial tcp 2.18.160.25:443: i/o timeout\nsuse-updater-opensuse.leap.15.0: Get \"https://support.novell.com/security/oval/opensuse.leap.15.0.xml\": dial tcp 130.57.66.5:443: i/o timeout\nsuse-updater-suse.linux.enterprise.server.11: Get \"https://support.novell.com/security/oval/suse.linux.enterprise.server.11.xml\": dial tcp 130.57.66.5:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2011-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2011.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2012-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2012.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2013-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2013.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2019-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2019.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2020-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2020.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2010-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2010.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2015-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2015.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2018-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2018.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2007-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2007.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2014-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2014.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2016-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2016.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2017-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2017.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2008-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2008.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2009-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2009.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2021-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2021.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\noracle-2022-updater: Get \"https://linux.oracle.com/security/oval/com.oracle.elsa-2022.xml.bz2\": dial tcp 95.101.178.195:443: i/o timeout\n","time":"2023-12-17T12:06:13Z","message":"errors encountered during updater run"}
```

And here is my docker setup:

```yaml
services:
  matcher:
    image: quay.io/projectquay/clair:4.7.2
    depends_on:
      clair-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      CLAIR_MODE: matcher
      CLAIR_CONF: /config/config.yaml
    volumes:
      - ./clair-config/:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: clair-matcher
    networks:
      - clair-network


  indexer:
    image: quay.io/projectquay/clair:4.7.2
    depends_on:
      clair-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./clair-config/:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: clair-indexer
    environment:
      CLAIR_MODE: "indexer"
      CLAIR_CONF: /config/config.yaml
    networks:
      - clair-network

  clair-database:
    container_name: clair-database
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - ./config/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - "pg_isready -U postgres"
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 4s
      retries: 12
      start_period: 10s
    networks:
      - clair-network

networks:
  clair-network:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

My SQL Init file.

```sql
CREATE USER clair WITH PASSWORD 'clair';
CREATE USER quay WITH PASSWORD 'quay';
CREATE DATABASE indexer WITH OWNER clair;
CREATE DATABASE matcher WITH OWNER clair;
CREATE DATABASE notifier WITH OWNER clair;
CREATE DATABASE quay WITH OWNER quay;
\connect matcher
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
\connect notifier
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
\connect quay
CREATE EXTENSION "pg_trgm";
```

And my clair.yaml

```yaml
# config.yaml ClairV4 https://quay.github.io/clair/reference/config.html

http_listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:6060      # This configures where the HTTP API is exposed.
introspection_addr: 0.0.0.0:6061    # This configures where Clair's metrics and health endpoints are exposed.
log_level: debug-color              # Set the logging level.
# tls: {}                           # TLS is a map containing the config for serving the HTTP API over TLS (and HTTP/2).
  # cert:                           # The TLS certificate to be used. Must be a full-chain certificate, as in nginx.
  # key:                            # A key file for the TLS certificate. Encryption is not supported on the key.

# ===== INDEXER
indexer:                            # ndexer provides Clair Indexer node configuration.
  connstring: host=clair-database port=5432 user=clair dbname=indexer sslmode=disable # libpq connection string.
  scanlock_retry: 10                # +integer representing seconds. This value tunes how often a waiting Indexer will poll for the lock.
  layer_scan_concurrency: 5         # +integer limiting the number of concurrent layer scans. Value tunes the number of layers an Indexer will scan in parallel.
  migrations: true                  # Whether Indexer nodes handle migrations to their database.
  scanner: {}                       # Scanner allows for passing configuration options to layer scanners.
    # dist:                         # A map with the name of a particular scanner and arbitrary yaml as a value.
    # package:                      # A map with the name of a particular scanner and arbitrary yaml as a value.
    # repo:                         # A map with the name of a particular scanner and arbitrary yaml as a value.
  airgap: false                     # Disables HTTP access to the Internet for indexers and fetchers.


# ===== MATCHER
matcher:                            # Matcher provides Clair matcher node configuration.
  connstring: "host=clair-database port=5432 user=clair dbname=matcher sslmode=disable" # libpq connection string.
  indexer_addr: "clair-indexer:6060" # A Matcher contacts an Indexer to create a VulnerabilityReport. Required!
  # cache_age:                      # Controls how long clients should be hinted to cache responses for.
  migrations: true                  # Whether Matcher nodes handle migrations to their databases.
  period: "1h"                      # Determines how often updates for new security advisories will take place. Default 6h.
  disable_updaters: false           # Whether to run background updates or not.
  update_retention: 2               # Sets the number of update operations to retain between garbage collection cycles. Default 10.
matchers:                           # Matchers provides configuration for the in-tree Matchers and RemoteMatchers.
  names:                            # A list of string values informing the matcher factory about enabled matchers. 
    - alpine
    - aws
    - debian
    - oracle
    - photon
    - python
    - rhel
    - suse
    - ubuntu
    - crda
  config: {}                         # Provides configuration to specific matcher. Example https://quay.github.io/clair/reference/config.html#matchersconfig
updaters:                            # Updaters provides configuration for the Matcher's update manager.
  sets:                              # A list of string values informing the update manager which Updaters to run. If value is nil default set of Updaters will run.
    - alpine
    - aws
    - debian
    - oracle
    - photon
    - pyupio
    - rhel
    - suse
    - ubuntu
  config: {}                         # Provides configuration to specific updater sets. Example https://quay.github.io/clair/reference/config.html#updatersconfig
```

Comment: Seems like material for a bug report... Speaking of which, did you check bugtrackers for the software in use? In any case, it would help if there weren't multiple issues in one question but one, accompanied by a [mcve].

Comment: I want to give an all around minimal approach, especially for people who are looking for an example that can be used because there aren't that many working Clair Compose files. I will minimize it a little bit and reduce it to one question. But still think the questions are clear and reproducible O:-)